# Rotate and scale image view with anchor points android

Tags: android

How to rotate and scale the image view with points around the corner of the image like in MS OFFICE. So that the points will be the  anchor points of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the anchor point located at (5, 20)

1. Move the image so that the anchor point will be at (0, 0) by moving the image to (-5, -20)
2. Rotate & Scale
3. Move the the resulted image by (5, 20) so that the anchor point will be located back at (5, 20)